# Formats supported by SAP PI for non-SAP to SAP integration

Tags: integration, sap-erp, sap-pi, sap-xi

I want to send my data to SAP through PI from windows server.

I am currently having a system which is using text file(.txt) to send the data from my windows server to PI. Then PI decodes it to IDOC and sends it to SAP. Since this file is created by a SQL query,it is creating errors and messages get failed in PI due to some extra space or other alignment issues.

I am thinking if there is any other convenient file format(eg. csv,xls,xml) that are supported by PI which I can use to communicate to SAP ERP.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PI can pretty much convert from any format you give it, they key is to create a mapping that interprets the incoming format and then converts it to the outgoing format. Because you want to send a file format that is stable (for lack of a better term) I would suggest to extract it from SQL in an XML format and then you can create  a message mapping. If you are not able to then you might need to develop a Java mapping that allows you strip out spaces and alignments etc.

Later....